# Open Office - Execute function

Tags: system, exec, openoffice.org

Does anyone know of a macro function in OpenOffice like `exec()` or `system()` in other languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SystemShellExecute](http://api.openoffice.org/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/system/SystemShellExecute.html)